# Let R be the relation defined on the set of bijective functions from the set (1 to n) to the set (1 to n) by $fRg$ whenever $f = g^{-1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am not too sure as to what the relation is but I think $R = \{(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), ..., (n - 1, n)\} $.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. $R$ is a relation *between functions*. So its elements should be pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are both functions, not numbers.

Comment: What do you mean you aren't sure what the relation is? You defined the relation in the title

Comment: Well I have to prove whether or not R is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric or transitive. Do I not have to write out the numbers? Could I say that $f(1) = 2$, $f(2) = 3$ and so on?

Comment: Do you know what the definitions of reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and transitive are?

Comment: I do, but the textbook I have uses pairs of numbers for the examples.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $R$ is reflexive you would need to show that $f R f$ for every $f.$ Is it the case that $f=f^{-1}$ for every $f?$

To show that $R$ is symmetric you would need to show that $f R g$ implies $g R f$ for every $f, g.$ Is it the case that $f=g^{-1}$ implies $g=f^{-1}$ for every $f, g?$

To show that $R$ is antisymmetric you would need to show that $f R g$ implies it is not the case that $g R f$ for every $f, g.$ Is it the case that $f=g^{-1}$ implies $g\neq f^{-1}$ for every $f, g?$

To show that $R$ is transitive you would need to show that $f R g$ and $g R h$ implies $f R h$ for every $f, g, h.$ Is it the case that $f=g^{-1}$ and $g=h^{-1}$ implies $f=h^{-1}$ for every $f, g, h?$

Answer (score 0):

For example, if $f,g : \{1,\dots,n\} \to \{1,\dots,n\}$ are defined by $$f(i) = \begin{cases} i+1 & \textrm{if } i < n \\ 1 & \textrm{if } i=n \end{cases} \qquad g(i) = \begin{cases} n & \textrm{if } i = 1 \\ i-1 & \textrm{if } i>1 \end{cases}$$ it is easy to see that $f$ and $g$ are inverses to each other, and then the pair $(f,g)$ is an element of $R$.